# How to integrate $\int\frac{2x+1}{\sqrt{x+3}}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I'm trying to solve this:

$$\int\frac{2x+1}{\sqrt{x+3}}dx$$

I  was thinking in use substitution technique but if I take my $u$ as $x+3$, my $du$ isn't what is left.

Answer (score 5):

Note that $u$ substitution with your recommendation, $u=x+3$, yields the integral $$\int \frac{2x+1}{\sqrt{u}} du.$$ Let us try to get this integral entirely in terms of $u$. Notice that $x=u-3$, so the integral will turn out to be $$\int \frac{2(u-3)+1}{\sqrt{u}}du.$$ Now expanding the numerator and then dividing each term in the numerator by $\sqrt{u}$ will let you use the reverse power rule to get a solution.

Comment: +1. Nice answer. Succinct and doesn't spoil the answer with too much detail. Just what's needed for someone to learn from it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are on the right track but just didn't complete the thought:

Taking $u=x+3 \implies du= dx$

Note that $2x+1= 2(x+3)-5=2u-5$

$$\int\frac{2x+1}{\sqrt{x+3}}dx= \int\frac{2u-5}{\sqrt{u}}du=2\int u^{1/2}du-5\int u^{-1/2}du$$

What's next?

Comment: but from where comes $2x+3$? Is $2x+1$ on the numerator.

Comment: That was an error on my part. I think I have fixed it now.

Comment: ok thank u very much!!! understood

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more general method.

Consider the integral
$$I=\int \frac{a_1x+a_2}{\sqrt{a_3x+a_4}}dx$$
We may preform the substitution $x=\frac{u-a_4}{a_3}$
$$I=\frac1{a_3}\int \frac{\frac{a_1}{a_3}u-\frac{a_4}{a_3}+a_2}{u^{1/2}}du$$
$$I=\frac1{a_3^2}\int\frac{u}{u^{1/2}}du+\frac1{a_3}\bigg(a_2-\frac{a_4}{a_3}\bigg)\int\frac{du}{u^{1/2}}$$
$$I=\frac{2u^{3/2}}{3a_3^2}+\frac{2u^{1/2}}{a_3}\bigg(a_2-\frac{a_4}{a_3}\bigg)$$
$$I=\frac{2u^{3/2}}{3a_3^2}+\frac{2u^{1/2}}{a_3^2}(a_2a_3-a_4)$$
$$I=\frac{2\sqrt{a_3x+a_4}}{3a_3^2}\bigg(a_3(x+3a_2)-2a_4\bigg)+C$$
All that remains is for you to plug in your constants.

Answer (score 1):

I am quite surprised that nobody yet, suggested, substituting $x+3 = u^2$, this would make your integral very easy to solve.

You will get $dx = 2u.du$, and this $u$ will be cancelled by one in denominator and now you can just substitute $x$ in $2x+1$ with $u^2-3$, and you're pretty much ready to get your answer.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int\frac{2x+1}{\sqrt{x+3}}dx=\int\frac{2(x+3)-5}{\sqrt{x+3}}d(x+3)=\int\frac{2u-5}{\sqrt u}du$$
$du=dx$ is not always true, but $dx=\frac{dx}{du}du$ is true. Or if you want to get rid of notation $d(x+3)$, just use
$$\int\frac{2x+1}{\sqrt{x+3}}dx=\int\frac{2u-5}{\sqrt u}\frac{dx}{du}du=\int\frac{2u-5}{\sqrt u}du$$

Answer (score 0):

Using $2x+1 = 2(x+3) - 5$, your integral becomes: 
\begin{equation}
 \int\frac{2x+1}{\sqrt{x+3}}dx
 =
 \underbrace{{\displaystyle\int}\sqrt{x+3}\,\mathrm{d}x}_A- \underbrace{{\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x+3}}\,\mathrm{d}x}_B
\end{equation}
We know that 
\begin{align}
 A &= \dfrac{2\left(x+3\right)^\frac{3}{2}}{3}\\
 B &= 2\sqrt{x+3}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Consider the general case of 
$$I=\int \frac{a x+b}{\sqrt{c x+d}}\,dx$$ Let
$$cx+d=t^2 \implies x=\frac{t^2-d}{c}\implies dx= \frac{2 t}{c}\,dt$$ making 
$$I=\int \left(\frac{2 (b c-a d)}{c^2}+\frac{2 a }{c^2}t^2 \right)\, dt=\frac{2 (b c-a d)}{c^2}t+\frac{2 a }{3c^2}t^3+K$$

Answer (score 0):

Another direct way could be partial integration:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \int\frac{2x+1}{\sqrt{x+3}}dx 
& = & \int \underbrace{(2x+1)}_{u}\cdot \underbrace{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+3}}}_{v'}dx  \\
& = & (2x+1)\cdot 2\sqrt{x+3} - \int 2 \cdot 2 \sqrt{x+3} \; dx \\
& = & 2 (2x+1)\cdot \sqrt{x+3} - \frac{8}{3}(x+3)\sqrt{x+3} \: \: ( + C )\\
& = & \frac{2}{3}(2x-9)\sqrt{x+3}\: \: ( + C )
\end{eqnarray*}$$